# Baseline of UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

Auto layout is able to sync the `NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline` and the `NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline` with UILabel's baselines. Is there any way to read out these values without auto layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a private API for getting the CoreText information used for rendering the text within UILabel.